# Kendo ui remove number filter spinner

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have this filter field with arrows that increase or decrease numbers and I want to remove them
[image]

As far I've tried several solutions that didn't help

```
{
                field: "TotalEnergyCharge",
                title: "Calc Total",
                format: "{0:n2}",
                width: "70px",
                headerAttributes: {
                    style: "overflow: visible; white-space: normal; text-align: center; font-weight: bold"
                },
                attributes: {
                    style: "text-align: right"
                },
                operator: "eq",
                filterable: {
                    cell: {
                        operator: "eq",
                        showOperators: false
                    }
                },
                spinners: false,
                editor: function (container, options) {
                        $('<input data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                            .appendTo(container)
                            .kendoNumericTextBox({
                                spinners: false
                            });
                    }
            },
```

Answer (score 2):

You couldn't remove because both ways you're trying are meant to work in a different way. The `spinners` before `editor` won't work at all, and the `spinners` option for the widget located inside `editor` will work only when user edits a row.

Now, for the filter widget, I couldn't find anything strightforward to use, like an event or method as used in `editor`. It seems that there is nothing like that for filters.

So I did a trick after grid initialization, changing the filters' fields options:

```
$('#grid .k-filter-row input[data-role="numerictextbox"]').each((i, el) => {
    $(el).data('kendoNumericTextBox').setOptions({ spinners: false });
});
```

[Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/eGecOhEb)

Modify the selector to get the filters you like to remove the spinners.

Note that `setOptions` is not listed as a method in the NumericTextBox documentation. Kudos for Kendo!!

Comment: Alternatively, code similar to OP's `editor` could be used in [filterable.cell.template](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.filterable.cell#columnsfilterablecelltemplate)

Comment: @GaloisGirl that's great. Better than what I proposed. I couldn't find that parameter when searching to write this answer. Thank you. You should write an answer with that option.

Comment: I'm too lazy :) Go for it if you want. :)